# Adding a 'license' field to a schema.org Place record

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have a database of locations that I would like to publish as Open Data. each record can have one of several licenses depending on where the data was sourced from so each record needs to have a license attached. I'm publishing the data as `json-ld`. Sample record:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Place",
  "name": "METROPOLITAN MUSEUM OF ART",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "1000 5TH AVE",
    "addressLocality": "NEW YORK",
    "addressRegion": "NY",
    "addressCountry": "United States",
    "postalCode": "10028-0198"
  },
  "hasMap": "http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=40.7784&mlon=-73.9627#map=15/40.7784/-73.9627",
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": 40.7784,
    "longitude": -73.9627
  },
  "description": null,
  "telephone": "+1 (212) 472-2764",
  "url": "http://www.metmuseum.org",
  "openingHours": null,
  "photo": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "contentUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8888/fSunhLAJFSmnx55GNJee2-YKcgE=/1000x1000/museums/logos/000/149/449/original/NYC_-_Metropolitan_-_Temple_of_Dendur.JPG",
    "creator": "Jean-Christophe BENOIST",
    "license": "CC BY 3.0"
  }
}
```

The schema.org [Place model](https://schema.org/Place) doesn't have a field for 'license'. What is the correct way to add a license type field to the record? Essentially I want to embed a [CreativeWork](https://schema.org/CreativeWork) field in there if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want to provide a license for the document that is *about* the `Place`, not for the `Place` itself.

So go with [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) (or one of its sub-types, like [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) if the document is a web page) and make use of its [`license`](http://schema.org/license) property.

To state that this `CreativeWork` is about the `Place`, you could use the [`about`](http://schema.org/about) property, and to state that the `Place` is the primary entity described in this document, you could use the [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) property.

If you want to keep `Place` as the top-level node, you could use JSON-LD’s [`@reverse`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#reverse-properties) for the `about` property, and use `mainEntity`’s inverse property, [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage).

Comment: I think I get the concept, just not 100% sure of the implementation. I do want to keep it as a Place as the data is really about the place. Do I just add a "mainEntityOfPage" key with a creativeWork as a child?

Comment: @barnaclebarnes: It shouldn’t matter which one is the top-level node (the `Place` or the `CreativeWork`) as the properties `mainEntity` and `mainEntityOfPage` are defined to be inverse; you’d have a `Place` in both cases. So use whatever works better for you. ··· If you don’t publish corresponding web pages about the data (i.e., a page for each location), you might want to use [`Dataset`](http://schema.org/Dataset): `Dataset → mainEntity → Place` or `Place → mainEntityOfPage → Dataset`.

Answer (score 1):

Using http://schema.org/Dataset (which is a type of `CreativeWork`) will allow you to set a license. `Place` is a field within `Dataset` so they fit together. The `license` for your `ImageObject` should also be the [URL of the license](https://schema.org/license) not the text (which I found out after having issues with it).

Dataset includes `datasetTimeinterval`, `distribution`, `includedDataCatalog` and `spatial` (a `Place`). Dataset was only [introduced in May](http://schema.org/version/2.0/)